# Stack trace with tiered output

Tags: multithreading, debugging, go, dump, tee

I am debugging a go program with a lot of goroutines which seem to deadlock.

I would like to have a stack trace when it freezes. But the output is long and doesn't fit my terminal buffer. So I want to output it to a file. However, if I output stderr to a file, I can't (easily) detect when it freezes.

I expected `tee` would be good for this:

`go test ./foo -v |& tee log.txt`

However, when I hit `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `\`, no stack trace output is shown either in terminal or in file. Somehow, it seems it doesn't survive the trip through `tee`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: try `go test ./foo -v | tail -f log.txt`

Comment: A core dump always goes to a file, but you need to set `GOTRACEBACK=crash` and use `SIGABRT`

Comment: Always? The core dump goes to the terminal if stderr goes to terminal and I give `SIGQUIT`.

Comment: That's not a core dump, that's the stack trace.

Comment: Indeed you are right :/ edited the question

Comment: Try `go test ./foo -v |& { trap "" 3; tee log.txt; }`

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment from [Mark Plotnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554472/mark-plotnick) , trapping the `SIGQUIT` signal before the `tee` works (at least for me):

`go test ./foo -v |& { trap "" 3; tee log.txt; }`